# PHP Loop not breaking

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using php loop in order to get to know any file changes. If the file changes occur , I am trying to stop the loop. But in my condition instead of stopping ..loop continues.

```
Route::get('api.chat.buffer/{job_id}',function($job_id){
    $award= DB::table('job_awards')->where('job_id',$job_id)->first();

        $dirname = base_path().'/files/chat/';
        $filename = $award->client_id.'_'.$award->user_id.'.timelog.log';
        $i =1;
        for($z=0;$z<=20;$z++){
            $current_file_time = filemtime($dirname.$filename);
            if($_GET['timestamp']<$current_file_time){
                echo json_encode(array('status'=>'success','data'=>$current_file_time,'node'=>1)); die;
                break;
            }
            sleep(1); // this should halt for 3 seconds for every loop
        }

    echo json_encode(array('status'=>'success','data'=>$current_file_time,'node'=>0));
    die;
});
```

I am creating chatting script and tracking changing while file change.

Thanks

Comment: Did this line `echo json_encode(array('status'=>'success','data'=>$current_file_time,'node'=>1)); die;` is executed ? and why did you added `die` in it ?

Comment: no its not...  even the condition matched.. but not.. its always going  ..on node=>0  last line

Comment: Try to add, before if statement, `echo $_GET['timestamp']` and `echo $current_file_time` to see if this condition is ever satisfied ?

Comment: inside `if` simply write `echo hello;`(only this comment others) and check it's printing or not ? i think your logic never comes inside if in any case

Comment: Array
(
    [current_file_time] => 1469986444
    [get] => 1469985108
)
Here is the output

Comment: condition is not satifying ..each time .. its giving same filemtime.. instead of giving new filemtime..

Comment: it's because you are trying to get modified time for the same file !!

Comment: @Maraboc  : but i have to get modified time.. of same file...How to do then.?

Comment: I i have written following line after loop and it works.. I wonder why
f($_GET['timestamp']<filemtime($dirname.$filename)){
   die;
  }

Comment: You should debug or insert flags to check the value of $z variable wich will control your loop. Also, the break statement is not required. In this case, you may use a while loop instead a for.

Answer (score 0):

can you use sleep function inside a for loop?. Have you tried with yield. Try assigning the numbers of loops statements to break; in this case it would be **break 1;** http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: condition is not satifying ..each time .. its giving same filemtime.. instead of giving new filemtime..

Comment: $current_file_time = filemtime($dirname.$filename);

Comment: I dont know.. but on last line.. I wrote this.. and its working
if($_GET['timestamp']<filemtime($dirname.$filename)){
   die;
  }

Comment: I do't know how you are passing your timestamp - format -. do and print_r, var_dump or echo to see what is wrong with the conditions where you are comparing $current_file_time against $_GET['timestamp']